# Cannot initialize a variable of type 'bool' with an rvalue of type 'void'

Tags: c++, object, compiler-errors

I fixed other issues I've been having with this project, and now I'm receiving just one error:

> Cannot initialize a variable of type 'bool' with an rvalue of type 'void'

I've defined an add method using an ArrayList Class.

*LineItemClass.h*

```
class LineItemClass{
    
private:
    
    int quantity;
    ProductClass product;       ///Creating object from ProductClass

public:
    
    //Non-Default constructor for LineItemClass
    LineItemClass(ProductClass product, int quantity);
    
    //sets product class to public so variables within it could be accessed
    ProductClass getProduct(){return product;}
    
    //Accessor & mutator for the quantity of items ordered
    int getQuantity(); ///Accessor / getter for quantity
    
    void setQuantity(int quantity); ///Mutator / setter for quantity
    
    //Method to calculate total price of item and the quantity ordered
    double CalcTotalPrice();
}; //LineItem Class
```

*ArrayListClass.h*

```
template <class LineItemClass>
class ArrayList{
    
private:
    LineItemClass *data;
    int arrayLength; // length of actual array
    int listSize;    // number of elements list contains
    void resize();   // resizes the array if necessary
    bool needToResize(); //determines if we need to resize
    
public:
    //constructor
    ArrayList(){
        
        //get an array set up
        data = new LineItemClass[5];
        //initalize parameters
        arrayLength = 5;
        listSize = 0;
    }
    
    //accessor
    bool contains(LineItemClass item);
    int indexOf(LineItemClass item);
    int lastindexOf(LineItemClass item);
    LineItemClass get(int index);
    int size();
    
    //Modifiers
    void add(LineItemClass item);
    void add(int index, LineItemClass item);
    void set(int index, LineItemClass item);
    void remove(int index);
    void remove(LineItemClass item);
};
```

*InvoiceClass.h*

```
class InvoiceClass{
    
private:
    //list object of line items
    ArrayList <LineItemClass> lineItem;
    
public:
    
        
    //Method creates new line items to be added to the line item array
    void add(int quantity, class ProductClass product);
    
    //gets total amount of all line items
    double getAmountDue();
    
    //Displays invoice (to be called in main)
    void printData();
    
    
}; //Invoice Class
```

*LineItemClass.cpp*

```
//Non-Deafult constructor to set private variables
LineItemClass::LineItemClass(ProductClass product,int quantity){
    
    this->product = product;
    this->quantity = quantity;
}

int LineItemClass::getQuantity(){return quantity;} ///Accessor / getter for quantity

void LineItemClass::setQuantity(int quantity){this->quantity = quantity;}///Mutator / setter for quantity


//Method to calculate total price of item and the quantity ordered
double LineItemClass::CalcTotalPrice(){
    
    //Sets total price to the quantity ordered multiplied by the price of each item
    double totalPrice = this->quantity * product.getPrice();
    
    return totalPrice;  ///Returns total Price
}
```

*ArrayList.cpp*

```
template <class LineItemClass>
void ArrayList<LineItemClass>::resize(){
    
    //resize the array so it can accomadate more data
    //precondition - size of the array == size of the data
    //postcondition - new array thats twice the size
    
    //get a new temo array
    
    LineItemClass *temp = new LineItemClass[arrayLength * 2];   ///Created new array
    
    for(int i =0; i < arrayLength; i++) ///copied data over using loop
    temp[i] = data[i];
    data = temp;                        ///Makes sure data array is pointing to the temp array
    arrayLength *= 2;
    
}

template <class LineItemClass>
bool ArrayList<LineItemClass>::needToResize(){
    
    //Returns if the data is equal to the array list
    return arrayLength == listSize;
}

template <class LineItemClass>
void ArrayList<LineItemClass>::add( LineItemClass item){
    
    //add the item to the end of the list
    
    //check to see if there's enough space
    if(needToResize())
        resize();
    
    data[listSize] = item;
    listSize ++;
}

template <class LineItemClass>
void ArrayList<LineItemClass>::add(int index, LineItemClass item){
    
    //add item to the indicated index
    //everything else gets bumped down
    
    if (needToResize())
        resize();
    
    for(int i = listSize; i >= index; i--){
        data[listSize + 1] = data[listSize];
    }
    
    data[index] = item;
    listSize ++;

}
```

*InvoiceClass.cpp*

```
#include "Functions.h"

void InvoiceClass::add(int quantity, ProductClass product){
    
    LineItemClass oneLine = LineItemClass(product,quantity);
    
    bool add = lineItem.add(oneLine); //Error here//
}
```

Let me know if you need further specifications.

Comment: [`std::list::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back) returns nothing. What is the variable `add` for?

Comment: "trying to assign them to a bool variable" what is "them"? new items? the list?

Answer (score 1):

[`std::list::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back) returns nothing.

You should give up assigning and simply add an item.

```cpp
void InvoiceClass::add(int quantity, ProductClass product){
    
    LineItemClass oneLine = LineItemClass(product,quantity);
    
    // no assignment, just add an item
    lineItem.push_back(oneLine);
    
}
```

Comment: How would I go about adding?

Comment: First thing to do should be defining "adding".